# Validating user input in java?

Tags: java

My guessing game takes either 5, 10, or 20 guesses from a user and they are supposed to try to guess a random number chosen by the computer. Everything in my code is working except this: when the code asks the user whether they want 5, 10, or 20 guesses, if the user were to enter 15, for example, which is not one of the options, it goes on and starts asking for their guesses. I need some type of validation that will make sure they enter one of the options. I'm not sure where or how to include this in the correct way since I am new to programming. I've tried several different ways but get errors for all. What I need is if the user puts a number that is not one of the options, it should just ask them again until they input one of the options. Can someone show me how I should do this?

Comment: To improve this question, you should show one or two of the ways you tried and the errors you got. It's not likely someone will just give you a code as that's not what this site is intended for.

Comment: what did you tried and what errors you got in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take input from the user inside a loop. For example:

```
System.out.print("How many guesses would you like? (5, 10, 20)");
do {
    int numberOfGuesses = scan.nextInt();
    //on correct guess, break out of the loop
    if(numberOfGuesses == 5 || numberOfGuesses == 10 || numberOfGuesses == 20)
        break;
System.out.print("Please enter a guess having one of these values (5, 10, 20)");
} while (true);
```

Unless the user, enters one of the three values, he/she will kept being prompted to enter a correct guess value.

Comment: Prompting with the *same* exact question is not very user friendly... It will make more sense to alert the user that he/she chose an *invalid* option.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `if (answer.length() ==3)` makes no sense.
Maybe you meant:

```
if(answer.equals("yes"))
```

Besides, to accomplish what you want I would use a `Set` containing the valid guesses numbers. It is scalable and makes much more sense than checking against multiple values in an `if` clause. It will look like this:

```
Set<Integer> validNumberOfGuesses = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 10, 20));
int numberOfGuesses = scan.nextInt();
while (!validNumberOfGuesses.contains(numberOfGuesses)) {
    /* ask again */
    System.out.println(numberOfGuesses + " is not a valid number of guesses, please try again");
    numberOfGuesses = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has the `continue` keyword that jumps to start of the current loop when run. See [The Continue Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) documentation.

Once you have your user input you can do something like

```
if (numberOfGuesses != 5 && numberOfGuesses != 10 && numberOfGuesses != 20) {
  continue; // jumps to start of while loop block, without running conditional
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the "numberOfGuesses" you should check the value of that number before moving on. Otherwise you just move on in your code because you don't actually validate the number.

It may be a good idea to creat a function that returns a boolean value and then you can check the number there.

`boolean isValidOption(int number)`

In the function you want to perform some comparison and validate. Since you have three options you can opt for something like

`if (number == 5 || ... )`

You can consider how you'll verify the value as there are many ways. Just compare with valid numbers you know you want, you can do some `if` statements, or place the numbers in an array and compare the value while iterating through the array, and so on. Hope that helps you get started and happy coding!

Edit: Lastly I should have mentioned, but you need to consider the flow of your code. A loop of somesort like `while(!isValidOption())` for your check should be use. Loop around the instructions until the user enters a valid option. You need to consider order of operations here in your code and understand the computer doesn't think for you. It does what you tell it, so understand what you are trying to tell it here. `I want to step into my game, if and only if, the condition of isValidOption is met` for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to stay in the loop until you get input that satisfy your demands for example you can use the following function

```
    private  int getNumberOfGuesses(Scanner scan) {
       int numberOfGuesses;
       boolean numberOfGuesesIsValid;
       do {
           System.out.println("How many guesses would you like? (5, 10, 20)");
           numberOfGuesses = scan.nextInt();
           numberOfGuesesIsValid = numberOfGuesses == 5 || numberOfGuesses ==  10 || numberOfGuesses == 20;

         if (!numberOfGuesesIsValid) {
             System.out.print("Wrong option !!!");
         }
       } while (!numberOfGuesesIsValid);
    return numberOfGuesses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code inside a loop to make sure the value is either 5,10 or 20

`while(numberOfGuesses!=5||numberOfGuesses!=10||numberOfGuesses=!20);`

and the condition `if(answer.length()==3` can cause errors. it means it will work every time the input is of length 3,even "noo"